# Macro is changing tab name

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel files in a folder. I want to convert each excel file(only sheet1) to csv file. I have done this by using below Macro. I am not able to figure which line in the code changing tab name with file name. I dont want to change tab name.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveasCSV()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim createObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set createObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ChDir "C:\Users\puttaraju.d\Desktop\Phase1"
Set dirObj = createObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\puttaraju.d\Desktop\Phase1")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False 
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

For every file, pop up open for asking do u want to save changes in file. I dont want to change current file. how can i add line of code to do that.

Comment: If you're saving as CSV, then the tab name will also be the file name. To prevent this, you'll have to save the files in an Excel format rather than a CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Try manually saving a workbook as CSV. You will see that it changes the tab name to match the filename (without the `.csv` extension).

What you can do is save a temporary copy of your worbook using `SaveCopyAs`, then open that copy, and save it as CSV (and close it and delete it).

Here's an old procedure of mine that does something similar, using a different approach. It saves a sheet as text: the sheet is copied to another temp workbook, then that workbook is saved as text. Adapt to suit your needs.

```
Sub SaveSheetAsTextFile(sourceSheet As Worksheet, textFilePath As String)
    Dim oldScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim thisbook As Workbook
    Dim tempbook As Workbook

    oldScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Copy sheet to a new temp workbook
    Set thisbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempbook = Workbooks.Add
    thisbook.Activate
    sourceSheet.Cells.Copy tempbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    ' Save as text file
    tempbook.ActiveSheet.SaveAs filename:=textFilePath, _
                                FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
    'FileFormat:=xlTextWindows  ' this puts text cells in "quotes"!

    tempbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = oldScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
SaveSheetAsTextFile Sheet1, "C:\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Yes your correct. Which line i need to add for avoiding the pop up( Save changes tab).

Comment: @Pavi: it's all in the answer.